# 'Except for' vs. 'Except on'

Tags: prepositions, collocation

I am available on weekdays, except on Thursdays.

I am available on weekdays, except for Thursdays.

I have found two threads talking about it, but in both of them there were suggestions to change the sentences. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would just say "I am available on all weekdays except Thursday." using "on" or "for" is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *for* is more appropriate here because this usage fits the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for):

> used as a function word to indicate an actual or implied enumeration or selection

In this case, you are selecting Thursday as the exception.  If you want to use *on*, it might be better to rephrase your statement as "I am available on Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, and Fridays," which fits this [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on):

> used as a function word to indicate a time frame during which something takes place

The difference is slight and I doubt anyone but a pedant would fault you for using either one.  As micsthepic mentioned, another option would be to omit the preposition entirely.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I know a lot of pedants who wouldn’t fault you for either. (...wouldn’t fault you *on* either? )

Answer (score 1):

The first construction sounds wrong. I think @AffableAmbler has identified why, in terms of mixing enumerations and time frames.

It may work in a different form:

> I am available during the week, except on Thursdays.